# Google sign in with firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication, angularfire, google-signin

How can I use `signInWithCredential()` instead of `signInWithPopup()`. `signInWithPopup` isn't working on my mobile phone google chromes browser, I've checked around and found out it is a known issue and to use `signInWithCredential()` instead. However I cant seems to get it to work, my current code using `signInWithPopup()` is as followed. Any kind soul can help me? Thanks

```
 login() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then(() => {
        this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(async (authState) => {
          resolve(authState);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: What's this known issue you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

To use `signInWithCredential`, you would need to initialize an AuthCredential with an OAuth ID token/access token.
For example:

```
const cred = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleIdToken, googleAccessToken);
firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(cred)
  .then(userCredential => {
    // Success.
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // error occurred.
  });
```

You can use the Google sign in library to get a Google ID token: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

This works for browsers only. If you are using this in other non-browser environments, you would need some third party OAuth library to get the corresponding OAuth credential.